# Get id of last record displayed (not inserted)

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a code that displays record from database in three columns, here I want to catch id of only last record displayed in column (do not take it as last record in database) I simply mean last thing displayed on screen in columns.

```
$i = 1;

$sql = "select * from customers ORDER by customers_name limit 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if ($i == 1) {
 echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<td><a href=\"customers.php?cust_id=" . $row['cust_id'] . "\">$row[cust_name]</a></td>";
if ($i == 3) {
 $i = 1;
 echo "</tr>";
}
else {
 $i++;
}
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: ypu have selected 10 records from the database and showing in table so do you want the id of the last records which is at 10th place in the table?

Comment: The above code will show 1 table cell per row ( ie: 1 column ) rather than 3. You might find `modulus` a better method to divide the row into 3 columns. ( ie: `$i > 0 && $i % 3==0` )

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this. Show us what output you're presently getting, and what it is you "want" as an output. There are a few ways to do this, but I probably will be suggesting the wrong thing.

Comment: @RamRaider, you're not looking very closely at the code. It does indeed provide three columns. OP all you need to do to get the last displayed id is to add something like `$last_id = $row['cust_id'];` before the closing `}` of your `while` loop. then you can do whatever with it

Comment: fair point @ElefantPhace - I must learn to read more carefully.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $last_row = $row;
   ...
}
echo 'Last ID'.$last_row['id']; //or 'cust_id'
//or
echo 'Last row:'.json_encode($last_row);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've probably misunderstood again but I take it you wish to find the last ID in each of the columns as opposed to merely the last ID  in whichever happens to be the final occupied / populated table cell? If that is the case then perhaps the logic below might be of interest to solve your conundrum.

```
/* a counter and an array to store last id in each column */
$i=0; $last=array( 'column_1'=>0, 'column_2'=>0, 'column_3'=>0 );

$tbl=array();
$tbl[]="<table border=1 cellpadding='5px'>";


/* This uses my db connection and query method so you would need to use yours instead */
while( $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){

    $id=$rs->id;
    $customer=$rs->cust_name;

    if( $i==0 ) {
        $tbl[]='<tr>';

    } elseif( $i > 0 && $i % 4==0 ) {
        $tbl[]='</tr>';         
        $i=0;
    }
    else {
        $tbl[]="<td id='c_{$id}'><a href='/customers.php?cust_id={$id}'>{$customer}</a></td>";

        if( $i % 1==0 && $i % 2!=0 && $i % 3!=0 ) $last['column_1']=$id;
        if( $i % 2==0 ) $last['column_2']=$id;
        if( $i % 3==0 ) $last['column_3']=$id;
    }
    $i++;
}
$tbl[]='</table>';

echo implode( PHP_EOL, $tbl );
echo '<pre>',print_r($last,true),'</pre>';
```